# React Native Styling: how to style "sub element"?

Tags: react-native

In web css, we can set css for **sub** element. Example:

```
<div class="test">
<p>abc</p>
</div>
```

And we can set the `<p>` css by:

```
.test p {
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Now in React Native, I have this:

```
<View style={myStyle.test}>
<Text>abc</Text>
</View>
```

How we can set the `<Text>` style by `myStyle.test`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't use like css children, you have to set a custom style for each element that you wanna use.

Answer (score 0):

CSS in react native is just a subset of web css and it doesn't allow you to do what you do in webCss. All you have is inline css. So you have to style them separately. You can avoid repeating by defining a common style object and pass that instead of repeating.

You can check out this library as well:

https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

According to docs

> All of the core components accept a prop named style. The style names and values usually match how CSS works on the web, except names are written using camel casing, e.g. backgroundColor rather than background-color

Now cascading is not supported in react-native, yo =u have to provide a style prop to each element for it to be styled.